# Date is not displayed correctly in my beamer

Tags: beamer, templates, date

The date is not displayed correctly in the inferior part of my slides.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}       % or try default, Darmstadt, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{serif}    % or try default, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\definecolor{ao(english)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[%
  physical paper width=8in, physical paper height=6in]
\title[Unal%iversidad Nacional de Colombia
]{}
\author{Juan Muñoz
}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

% These three lines create an automatically generated table of contents.
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: On my up-to-date TeXLive 2018 distribution, the date is correct on all slides.

Comment: how date should be displayed? with recent `mikterx` seems to be correct on all slides.